# SQL Error - cannot add foreign key constraints

Tags: error-message, mysql

I'm uploading a site to a new environment and getting the following error:

[image: error message]

**The assetfiles table structure:**
[image: The assetfiles table structure]

Answer (score 1):

Based on that description, my guess is you're running into #2 here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16969176/684) and you've got some inconsistent data in one of the three foreign key constraints that the SQL is trying to add.

Comment: Ok, how might I go about sorting that out? I uploaded the same DB to another host and it was fine.